# Cumulative Sum by Specific quantity up to value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a horizontal matrix of values in Excel that I want to be able to show a quantity in a series up to a predetermined total value.  If the last value in the series is less than the specified quantity then the value that will satisfy the cumulative sum is the value used.  Empty values thereafter.

For example: Max cumulative sum of 200 in 7 units of 30: 30,30,30,30,30,30,20.

Should be straightforward but I've had some trouble doing it.  Thanks.

I've tried nested if thens with conditional sums but the formulas seems more less helpful than the basic explanation of what's needed.

I can do most of the function but the nested if thens are too complex and are creating problematic edge cases.  Hoping someone has a more concise idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine some `MOD` and `INT` together, cell `A1`put this formula and drag it to the right:

```
=IF(COLUMN()<=200/30,30,IF(COLUMN()=INT(200/30)+1,MOD(200,30),""))
```

Obviously you can reference these `200` and `30` from an absolute cell address.

Example to add to 308 in steps of 14:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=IF(COLUMN()<=$A3/$A4,$A4,IF(COLUMN()=INT($A3/$A4)+1,MOD($A3,$A4),""))
```

Another example to add to 312 in steps of 14:

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/tour]

Comment: I am trying your solution and it works for several corresponding cells but the total doesn't add up to the desired total.  Here is my formula trying to add to 308 with 22 cells of 14 (or less for the last). IF(COLUMN()<=ROUND($D$2/$F$2,0),ROUND($D$2/$F$2,0),IF(COLUMN()=INT($D$2/$F$2)+1,MOD($D$2,ROUND($D$2/$F$2,0)),""))

Comment: D2 is 308 and F2 is 22

Comment: It produces a value of 14 nine times which adds to 126.  I need to reach 308 in this example in units of 14.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: When I paste your formula it reads 30 and 20 totalling 50 rather than 300.

Comment: @js80, it works for me, see edited answer. How do you know beforehand you'll end up with 22 cells. You need to use the 14 as a parameter, not the 22

Comment: Now strangely its stopped working.  Cannot understand what the issue is.

Comment: 312 and 14 is what I'm trying

Comment: @js80, see edited answer. All you had to do was changing the value in A3 in my example

Comment: Here was the issue I encountered.  I need to offset the column by where the cell that I'm starting the formula is located.  Strange but it works now.  Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196775/discussion-between-js80-and-jvdv).

Comment: It is also a good answer but contrary to the answer provided by chris neilsen, it seems taht the formula will only work if it starts from the first cell which is A1 in the provided example.

Comment: @TerryWeng if you not want to place it in A1 you can simply reference Column (A1)

Comment: Sorry JvdV if I did not make myself clear. I think your formula is only working from the beginning of the row (Column A in this case). In other words, what if I want to start the formula in C1 and drag it across board? I tired to apply your formula from Column C but it ends in Column G using js80's example of 200 and 30. I was expecting to see 30 from Column C to H and see 20 in Column I.

Comment: @TerryWeng Right, I get what you saying, that's solved with OP through chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Min` to determine the value for each cell, and `Index` to specify the range

Like this (also handle returning blanks for columns past the last value)

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/MIN($A$2-SUM(INDEX(4:4,1,1):INDEX(4:4,1,COLUMN()-1)),$A$3)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: It is quite a decent answer but it seems that the formula is only working from second cell onward (in your example the formula will not work in A4 but only from B4 onward) due to invalid reference of the column before A4.

Comment: @Terry that is correct.  To make it work from column A would add considerable complexity